# Different styles in same label

Tags: qgis, labeling, style, format

I have a multiline label made of 3 attributes made through an expression like:

```
"Length"  || '/' ||  "Level"  || '/' || '→ ' || "Bearing"  || ' ←'
```

I'd like to make the Length and Level lines in bold while maintaining the bearing in a normal style. You can expand this question in a more general sense, because I could use some different styles (font size etc) for the different attributes. 
Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT: i read about similar questions, but i didnt come up with any solution OR workaround. Im asking if anyone has come up with any yet lately.

Comment: Not sure it is supported yet cause I've unsuccessfully looked for this feature too, and a very good question. This is one of my last "damn ArcGis is still better on that" point. Actually i flagged your question as duplicate. but the fact that this question keep popping should question QGIS dev about the fact that this is really a painfully missing feature.

Comment: Also please note that no satisfactory answers has been given to the much up-voted original question in the first place...

Comment: yeah, thanks for the answer, i saw similar question but i made a new one on purpose becuse i kinda wanted an "updated" answer, to see if there were any news about this feature. Maybe there are some workarounds, but i didnt come up with one yet..

Comment: Well I totally agree on the need for an updated answer. It wont bother me if moderators reject my duplicate tag. The main problem with the proposed sub-optimal workaround is that it's totally incompatible with some advanced label positioning because you can't easily predict if 2 different labels rules will end up at the same place according to placement rules. Another notable incompatibility of this workaround is the EasycustomLabelling plugins, wich is very usefull in printed map.